# How to save a picture in Java into Multiple blob?

Tags: java, image, blob, inputstream, fileinputstream

As I described in the title, I tried to access a picture file several times using an `InputStream`, then save it to blob type database but the result is null for the second, third, and so on. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
File image1 = new File("src/template1.png").getAbsoluteFile();
File image2 = new File("src/template2.png").getAbsoluteFile();
InputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(image1);
InputStream in2 = new FileInputStream(image2);
long length1 = image1.length();
long length2 = image2.length();
pstmt.setString(1, jTextField18.getText().toUpperCase());
pstmt.setBlob( 2, in1, length1 );
pstmt.setBlob( 3, in1, length1 );
pstmt.setBlob( 4, in1, length1 );
pstmt.setBlob( 5, in1, length1 );
pstmt.setBlob( 6, in1, length1 );
pstmt.setBlob( 7, in2, length2 );
Pstmt.setBlob( 8, in2, length2 );
```

then the result is:

```
YR/21
[BLOB - 5.6 KiB]
[BLOB - 0 B]
[BLOB - 0 B]
[BLOB - 0 B]
[BLOB - 0 B]
[BLOB - 5.5 KiB]
[BLOB - 0 B]
```

I tried to use new `InputStream` like this code and another error occured. It says:
Row size too large(>8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DINAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

```
pstmt.setBlob( 2, in1, length1 );
image1 = new File("src/template1.png").getAbsoluteFile();
in1 = new FileInputStream(image1);
pstmt.setBlob( 3, in1, length1 );
image1 = new File("src/template1.png").getAbsoluteFile();
in1 = new FileInputStream(image1);
pstmt.setBlob( 4, in1, length1 );
```

I think the problem is answered and change into another problem. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @kdgregory: that should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call consumes the stream, and the subsequent calls get no data.  You need a separate InputStream for each call.

Comment: i tried to use another inputstream but its still cant read the same file, the result is still [BLOB - 0 B]

Comment: i'm sorry i give a misleading answer, I've tried use another inputstream and then some error occured. it says: Row size too large(>8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DINAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline @jtahlborn

Answer (score 0):

"Is there any way to save a picture to multiple blob?"

Yes, but your code will only work for small images. Instead, have a parent reference for the image and a children for the actual image, which will have the blobs. Make the children small and save only a chunk of the image to every one of them.

This will help you manage the space and it will be easier to back up.

For a reference on how to read a file in chunks, take a look here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245

Save the chunk of the image to the database using the while-loop that reads the file.

It could be a lengthy operation to save the file, so you could have a flag on the parent defining if the children were all loaded or not. Thus preventing other threads from reading incomplete images.

If you are using MySQL, there's this tutorial on how to read and write images: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/

Have fun.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, sorry for my ambiguity, what I'm trying to say is I want to save a picture in multiple blob, 1 blob 1 picture, like a.jpg in blob 1, a.jpg in blob 2, and so on, so the same picture in the different blob

Comment: Ok, in this case then you have to close the stream and re-open it... or use non-blocking IO, but I don't think the prepared statement can work with non-blocking. ... On a separate topic, your code could work if you saved the image to only one Blob and made references to the first one. It would save you a lot of space on the database. But I am not trying to change your requirements. Thanks for the clarification.